# Searching by Content Type or Content Type Id not returning results

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, highlighted-content-web-part, pnp-search-webparts

I'm setting up several aggregators on a SharePoint Online site collection page that surface documents of the same content types from different document libraries onto a single page.

So far the Highlighted Content web part has been hit or miss, at best, so I tried using the PnP Modern Search web parts and they don't work any better.

For 2 content types using the query:

```
ContentType:"[content type name]
```

Works fine.

For every other content type it brings up no results.

I can find no difference between the content types. I've even created more content types using the same structure as the others and they aren't getting picked up by either the HCWP or the PnP-SRWP

How do I get these content types to show up?

Comment: I'm guessing from the title that you also tried ContentTypeId ?

Comment: Went with ContentTypeId first

Answer (score 0):

How long have you created new content types? Make sure you have waited 24 hours to make these documents to be crawled for search.

Make sure the documents you want to return with the correct content types.

You could also provide some screenshots with us to understand your issue more correctly.

Comment: I added a new content type and that one worked after a day, so that might have been the issue.  The old content type was attached to an encrypted file so I'm hoping that's why it wouldn't come up..